# Strange behaviour Function within a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, lambda

I can't understand what is happening inside this code, it prints 13 only.

```
/*jshint loopfunc: true */
for(var i=0;i<13;i++)
    setTimeout(function(){console.log(i)},10);
```

The output is

```
13
13
...[10 times more]
13
```

How can I print 0,1,2,...,12 with lambdas like how I wish to do?

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example?rq=1

Comment: You dun been got by a closure!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
for(var i=0;i<13;i++) {
    (function(j){
        setTimeout(function(){console.log(j)},10); 
    }(i))
}
```

in your original code the `i` variable gets incremented all the way up to 13 and then gets used by each of the `console.log` statements. To fix the problem you can create an anonymous function and pass the `i` variable to it on each iteration of the loop, this effectively takes a snapshot of the value of `i` at the time the function was called so `console.log` prints out the desired values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(var i=0;i<13;i++)
    setTimeout(function(index){console.log(index)}.bind(this, i),10);
```